# Button Click in Website using VBA Code to launch from excel

Tags: excel, vba, buttonclick

I am trying to click on a button using VBA Code and its not working Can someone help
The below is HTML Code, where i would like to call oa3_toolbox_button in VBA
HTML CODE

```html
<div id="oa3_button_create_new">
    <span id="oa3_toolbox_create_new" class="oa3_toolbox_button"><img src="/i/spacer.gif" class="spacerImage" alt="spacer"></span>
</div>
<div id="oa3_create_new">
    <div class="oa3cn_title">Create New <input class="searchBox default" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="search_global_create" value="Search Global"></div>
</div>

    <div id="oa3_global_create_new">
        <a href="report.pl?action=crosstab;_object=account;app=ma;_app_context=global;uid=tD8oDgBD6xGA8YjiJoUMOA;_suppress_restore_selected=1;r=MdfxwCm4890">Account-wide: Report</a>
<a href="envelope.pl?app=te;uid=tD8oDgBD6xGA8YjiJoUMOA;r=AM3W4Lh2497;action=header;_new_envelope=1;cancel_action=paint;save_action=edit_ticket">Expenses: Expense report, New </a>
<a href="envelope.pl?app=te;uid=tD8oDgBD6xGA8YjiJoUMOA;r=D6OzL3q7177;action=header;_new_envelope=1;cancel_action=paint;save_action=list_ticket;_dupit=1">Expenses: Expense report, New clone </a>
<a href="schedulerequest.pl?app=ta;uid=tD8oDgBD6xGA8YjiJoUMOA;r=Yzhc2M84889;action=new_schedule_request;save_action=edit_schedule_request;_new_schedule_request=1">Timesheets: Schedule request</a>
<a href="timesheet.pl?app=ta;uid=tD8oDgBD6xGA8YjiJoUMOA;r=SkghL8P8262;action=new_sheet;cancel_action=paint;save_action=grid">Timesheets: Timesheet, New </a>
<a href="timesheet.pl?app=ta;uid=tD8oDgBD6xGA8YjiJoUMOA;r=qryePrr1810;action=new_sheet;cancel_action=paint;save_action=grid;_dupit=1">Timesheets: Timesheet, New clone </a>
    </div>
```

VBA Code

```vb
lookupURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/564b4b1b-03a5-44cf-868e-463eae00268f/saml2?SAMLRequest=jZHBasMwDIZfJfjeOHFc6pok4DYtFDoY7bbDbiLTaCC2M8spe%2FxlKT0Nyq5C%2Bvm%2BXyWB7QdtxnhxJ%2FwakWLybXtHFRuD0x6oI%2B3AIunY6rN5OmqRZtpihA%2BIwJJDU7G9ko1SyphiI%2BU23ygpi9XSyJ0Sedasdyx5w0CddxWbjqcbohEPjiK4OI0ykS1ysRDZS77SudCZTNfF8v137xmIuitW7BN6QpYYIgxxStp6R6PFcMZw7Vp8PR0rdolxIM05TDKpH9BBF9LWW07k2c1Kz7qP3Ybgo299z5K9Dy3O1dwB6nJmD%2F%2FpCO6srH5Exu9dlvyWXZf871PqHw%3D%3D"
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate lookupURL
    'enter code here`Yes this code is not working, hence commented it
    'IE.document.getelementbyId("oa3_button_create_new").Click
    'Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    Dim e
    'enter code here`Getting VBA Run-time error'462'; remote server machine 
    'does not exist or is '`enter code here`unavailable while executing the 
    'below line
    For Each e In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If e.innertext = "oa3_toolbox_button" Then
    e.parentelement.Click
    Exit For
    End If
    Next
```

Comment: `If e.className = "" ......` as it is the class attribute value not the `.innerText` you are targeting. `IE.document.getelementbyId("oa3_button_create_new").Click` would have been better. You have commented this out so I assume that didn't work? Also, are you sure this is the right bit of html?

Comment: You're not waiting for the page to lad after calling `IE.Navigate`

Comment: @Qharr - HTML Code is correct, however reiterated the code for better understanding... Also i am getting VBA Run-time error'462'; remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable while executing "For Each e In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("span")", hence updated the question too. Request for your help

Comment: @TimWilliams - I did write that, but its not helping me. Hence removed it

Comment: You need the wait - no point in trying without that.  If the page has not loaded then you can't access anything on it.